# I need to place a large A4 doc into an A3 doc. 2 A4 pages for each A3 page. How to do this quickly?

Tags: adobe-indesign, script

Part of a task I regularly have to do is to place A4 documents into A3 documents. 2 A4 pages side by side onto each A3 page. The A4 documents can be long, so it's a nuisance to have to place, size and position each A4 page.
[image: A4 docs across A3 doc]

Is there a way using a script or frames to automate this?

I am aware of the script for placing a multi page A4 - PlaceMultiplePagePDF - but this only does 1 pdf page per page of a document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your end product *has* to be an A3 InDesign document and/or you want to have control with the layout and for example scale the pages down a bit, you have to either write your own script or do a little bit of clicking like described here.

- Create a *Master* page.
- Make empty frames for the A4 pages. Make sure they have the proper aspect ratio by drawing 210x297 mm rectangles and scaling them to your needs.
- Set their *Content* to *Graphic* (this makes it possible to place content into them by clicking *inside* the frame).
- Assign an *Object Style* to the frames.
- Enter the *Object Style Options*, in *Frame Fitting Options* tick on *Auto-Fit* and set *Content Fitting > Fitting* to either *Fit Content Proportionally* or *Fill Frame Proportionally* (depending on your needs).

Here is an example with two frames with a border:

[image]

- Insert as many pages using the master as needed (and a few more just in case).
- Select *File > Place* and locate your A4 PDF.
- Insert the pages in the frames on at a time with one single click for each page.

[image]

Comment: Hi Wolff, thanks for the response. A solution indeed, it does simplify it somewhat, a single click on each frame will be great. I think perhaps I am looking for a script, if the document I am putting as an appendix to the main document is 200 pages it still means I have to set up 100 pages an click 200 frames. Still much better than what I was doing so very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the *Scripts* panel and locate *Application > Samples > JavaScript > PlaceMultipagePDF.jsx* and run it by double-clicking it.
- Select your A4 file and press *OK*.
- In the following dialogue set *Place PDF in* to *New Document* and press *OK*.

Now you have a single page document with all the A4 pages.

- Enter *File > Document Setup* and tick on *Facing Pages* and set *Start Page #* to *2*.

Now you facing pages. Starting with page 2 makes the first page become a left page instead of a lonely right page.

- Export a PDF in *Spreads* according to your needs.

Now you have an A3 PDF with all the A4 pages placed side by side.

Comment: Interesting, yes this does get around a lot of the work, splits it into 2 processes, but much faster. Great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you need imposition software ..
I assume that you need to arrange a bunch of pages in a certain sequence.
if you intend to do a booklet (let's say of 8 pages) so that last page (8) is facing the first page (1) and the page (7) is facing the page (2) ... and so on.
and you will bind the booklet from its center in our case it will be the centerline of an A3 folding line.

[image]

this is a case if you wish to bind a booklet from its centerfold of the A3 paper.
here you may need to combine your A4 paper into on PDF file and use one of the imposition software available there are many, some of them are stand-alone like  [KODAK PREPS Imposition](https://workflowhelp.kodak.com/display/PREPS90/KODAK+PREPS+Imposition+Software+9.0) and some of them are just a plugin into Acrobat like
[Quite Imposing Plus](http://www.quite.com/imposing/index.htm/)
I really like the plugin as it is easy to use.

but if you want just to arrange the photos in a sequence that page (1) is facing page (2) and the page (3) is facing page (4) and so on. you don't need to use the imposition software, even though it is easy the imposition software. bit actually there so many ways that you may achieve the same result, I will name two
first, you can print the A4's on an A3 paper using Acrobat PDF and the output could be to the printer directly or to a PDF file

[image]

in the above screenshot you may first choose the printer you want and select to print on "Multiple" or "booklet" and make sure to choose 2 pages per page.

if you want the output to be PDF so in the printer choose "Adobe PDF" and then enter into the properties of the Acrobat PDF printer and choose A3 as output paper in the "Adobe PDF page size" section

[image]

The second way is to use Adobe bridge and it will open photoshop contact sheet script. (of course you may use it directly from photoshop by going to File > Automate > Contactsheet II )
open acrobat bridge and browse to your project folder
choose two A4 Pages you want to merge into one and go to Tools > Photoshop > contact sheet this option will make a contact sheet with the selected pages .. make sure you select only two pages

and make sure to enter the A3 size in cm (29.7*42) and two columns and one row and the hereunder screenshot

[image]

Tell you the truth there are so many ways merging two A4 into A3 paper .. so many ways that I can not collect in one answer. some use scripts and some use software like Photoshop, CorelDraw, Illustrator, and similar to them some use data merge like InDesign, Illustrator, Photoshop, and professional imposition software, so many ways even I can merge two pages into one using excel and/or PowerPoint. it is a very common task and so many software can do so many even I cant imagine.